# How can I have a music track fade to a low gain/volume while I talk over it with a second audio track in Adobe Premiere Pro CC?

Tags: premiere

I'd like to know how I can setup two audio tracks where the following happens:

1. The first audio track (music) plays at full power/volume/gain.
2. A second audio track (narration) causes the first audio track to fade to a much lower volume (but still able to hear it) while the narration happens.
3. The second audio track (narration) finishes which causes the first audio track (music) to resume to it's normal/full volume.

I don't want any audio discontinuity to occur. Meaning, I want the first audio track (music) to play through while the narration happens.

I am using `Adobe Premiere Pro CC 7.2.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ducking is a great solution for broadcast audio (for example, muting crowd noise when a commentator is trying to explain what's happening on the field).  In production, the limitations of ducking become apparent: sometimes it's too much or too little, sometimes it needs to be faster than the default, or slower.  These are things that are not necessarily obvious the first time you listen, but become obvious after the second or third listening.

Broadcast audio production presumes you hear things only once, so the limitations of ducking are acceptable.  If you are producing material that people might watch more than once, you really should do the ducking manually, setting audio keyframes and moving the volume manually to maximize not only quality and intelligibility, but also emotion and impact.

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon is called audio ducking i.e. lowering of music when there's a voice being heard.

It's best to do this in Audition See this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMk0XUCUkDY). You can send your audio to Audition using [Dynamic Link](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/editing-audio-audition.html).

It may be possible to do this in Premiere itself using a VST plugin, but it's not straightforward or intuitive.